# Java avoid java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while reading a file but using streams at the same time

Tags: java, file, parallel-processing, stream, filereader

I'm trying to read a very large file with streams so I need parallel streams and not iterations per line... I'm trying as follows:

```
String cont = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(this.File_Path)),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);    
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(cont.split("\\PL+"));

yep = words.parallelStream()
            .filter(x -> x.contains(toMatch))
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works for small file size, but if I try to make the same with a file that has some gbs of size java gives me this exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Required array size too large
```

There is a way to avoid this exception but using parallel stream at the same time instead of iterate with BufferReader or Scanner?

Comment: Is the error on the line `cont.split("\\PL+")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Files.readAllBytes()`. It loads the whole content of the file in a `String`, therefore in memory.
To read line by line you want to use `Files.lines()` that returns a `Stream<String>` and then transform it into a parallel stream and do your transform operation on it :

```
List<String> words = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get(this.File_Path), charSetOfYourFileIfNotUTF8) // Stream<String>
         .parallel()
         .flatMap(s-> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\PL+"))) // Stream<String>
         .filter(x -> x.contains(toMatch))
         .distinct()
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

About performance, note that `distinct()` in parallel pipelines is expensive with an collect that maintain the order.
You should consider `toSet()` to improve further performance.

Comment: I already tried this method but using Files.lines give me another exception: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1.Tried also to pass Files.lines StandardCharsets.UTF_8 but nothing

Comment: Probably a charset mismatch between the file charset and the default charset. Try by setting UTF-8 explicitly as in the edit. Whatever you should use a compatible charset to prevent the issue.

Comment: I also added the charset as modified above but this isn't the problem.

Comment: Changing the charset to StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 now it works as well.

Comment: It means that your file was not in UTF-8 but in ISO_8859_1.

Answer (score 0):

The java heap memory is limited. We cannot read whole data of files at the same time. Over a certain size it is just impossible (unless you increase the heap memory, which is not ideal for few reasons). What I would recommend is, read the file in chunks like few lines, fixed size of 1000 lines maybe. Then run your operation of splitting into array and counting on that chunk.
You can parallelize chunks through multithreading.